# How to Fix text in Html with CSS

Tags: html, css

How I can to fixed Text(for example  ) in html or with css?
I use this code for my own website sidebar, but when I write long text `<span>` Comes down in this code 12 oct 2016 comes down 
 I use `display: inline-block` but this css code not avail..

```css
.widgetbox{
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius:3px;
}
.widgetbox .widgetboxTitle{
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 padding:5px 10px;
}
.widgetbox .contentarea{
 padding:7px;
 }
.widgetbox .newslist {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.widgetbox .newslist img {
 border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
 float: right;
 margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.widgetbox .newslist h3 {
 font-size: 14px;
}
.widgetbox .newslist span{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="widgetbox">
 <div class="widgetboxTitle">
 <h4>News</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="contentarea">
<div class="newslist">
 <img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8272330300/last_tech2.jpg" alt="ASUS">
 <h3>New Lap top</h3>
 <span>12 oct 2016</span>
</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `display: inline-block` to the `h3`:

```css
.widgetbox{
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius:3px;
}
.widgetbox .widgetboxTitle{
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 padding:5px 10px;
}
.widgetbox .contentarea{
 padding:7px;
 }
.widgetbox .newslist {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.widgetbox .newslist img {
 border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
 float: right;
 margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.widgetbox .newslist h3 {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.widgetbox .newslist span{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="widgetbox">
 <div class="widgetboxTitle">
 <h4>News</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="contentarea">
<div class="newslist">
 <img src="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8272330300/last_tech2.jpg" alt="ASUS">
 <h3>New Lap top</h3>
 <span>12 oct 2016</span>
</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: inline-block;` into the `.widgetbox .newslist h3` class as well.

Answer (score 1):

`h3` is a block element and so the span next to it will come down.Try making that `.widgetbox .newslist  h3{ display:inline-block;}`.Or try giving float left to both `h3` and the `span`